# How to find which queries are supported on a given query engine

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, duckdb

I'm trying to find a way to know which queries are supported on a given query engine. For example, I know that some queries that work on Postgresql won't work on sqlite.

I'm now searching for queries that would work on Snowflake and not on DuckDB (or vice versa) and this makes me wonder: what to search for in the documentation.

With this general question, I'm looking for some hint (hitch hiking tips) to look in the documentation of a query engine to see what sql keyword argument won't work.

Thank you very much for your help and your input !

Comment: Too bad https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance recently was deleted.

Comment: Assuming both DBMSs are ANSI SQL compliant you could exclude all the functionality that is part of the standard and only look at what remains. However, this would still be a very laborious task so I’m wondering why you would want to do it?

Comment: Thanks @NickW !

I'm trying to see if I can use duck db (querying pandas dataframe) to "unit test" queries that will ultimately run on Snowflake (on production). I would create mock data in pandas and test for edge cases.

As such, I want to know if all the queries working on Snowflake will work on my unit test scenario and I'm not sure how to check for that (I would like to avoid running all the SQL keywords that exists on each DBMS to check).

And because this use case could work for queries running on postgresql in production, I made my question larger.

Thanks !

Comment: Why not just test directly on Snowflake? Presumably if you have a Prod Snowflake account you also have a Dev Snowflake account? What you are proposing seems unnecessarily complicated and whatever you did there would still be no guarantee that what you tested against one DB would work (performantly) against another DB. Also, what would you do if you had to test something that is specific to Snowflake (Streams, Tasks, Stages, Warehouses, etc)?

Comment: Thanks @NickW. I see several point here.

First, I worked in some companies where we didn't always had dev Snowflake account.

Second, even when we had dev account, finding/generating data in Snowflake was cumbersome. I'm thinking that using python libraries like hypothesis in conjunction with duckdb could be a good way to generate interesting edge cases to test agains.

Last but not least: I opened the question not to mention this specific use cases because I'm interested also in knowing how to compare query engines.

I hope it's clearer.

Thanks